# how to set Eclipse editor screen & package explorer view?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, package-explorer

Actually i came up with a problem which i haven't faced from a long time. while doing project i usually see my package explorer & editor screen side by side, but i don't know what the thing happened they are displaying one on above. 
The following images explains the error..

[image: How i want my screen to be...]

[image: But it is displaying in this pattern]

can anyone help me how to get my editor screen & package explorer side by side......

Answer (score 13):

the problem is your class text editor is maximize and your project explorer ovelapped on text editor of class

you should do just `windows->Reset perspective->Yes` then eclipse reset your perspective...